# BeanUtils copyProperties to copy Arraylist

Tags: java, copy, apache-commons-beanutils

I know that BeanUtils can copy a single object to other.

Is it possible to copy an arraylist.

**For example:**

```
FromBean fromBean = new FromBean("fromBean", "fromBeanAProp", "fromBeanBProp");
ToBean toBean = new ToBean("toBean", "toBeanBProp", "toBeanCProp");
BeanUtils.copyProperties(fromBean, toBean);
```

**How to achieve this?**

```
List<FromBean> fromBeanList = new ArrayList<FromBean>();
List<ToBean> toBeanList = new ArrayList<ToBean>();
BeanUtils.copyProperties(fromBeanList, toBeanList);
```

It's not working for me. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have two lists of equals size then you can do the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < fromBeanList.size(); i++) {
     BeanUtils.copyProperties(toBeanList.get(i), fromBeanList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Ya now i did it like this But i want to know to copy fully at once thanks

Comment: Don't forget that copyProperties only copies properties that have a public set method it does not use reflection.

Answer (score 19):

If you have a list origin with data and list destination empty, the solution is:

```
    List<Object> listOrigin (with data)
    List<Object> listDestination= new ArrayList<Object>(); 

     for (Object source: listOrigin ) {
        Object target= new Object();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(source , target);
        listDestination.add(target);
     }
```

Comment: This one is actually the correct implementation rather than the accepted answer.!

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to write your own generic copy class.

```
class CopyVector<S, T> {
    private Class<T> targetType;
    CopyVector(Class<T> targetType) {
        this.targetType = targetType;
    }
    Vector<T> copy(Vector<S> src) {
        Vector<T> target = new Vector<T>();
        for ( S s : src ) {
            T t = BeanUtils.instantiateClass(targetType);
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(s, t);
            target.add(t);
        }
        return target;
    }
}
```

A step further would also be to make the List type generic - this assumes you want to copy Vectors.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
for(int i=0; i<fromBeanList.size(); i++){
  BeanUtils.copyProperties(toBeanList.get(i) , fromBeanList.get(i) );
}
```

Hope this helps..

Oops it is already explained by someone now..

anyways try it.

Answer (score 0):

[BeanUtils.copyProperties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29), It only copy the property of same name. So, In case of ArrayList you can't do that.

According to docs:

> Copy property values from the origin bean to the destination bean for
>   all cases where the property names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In spring BeanUtils.copyProperties, arguments are just opposite than apache commons lib

```
for(FromBean fromBean: fromBeanList) {
    if(fromBean != null) {
        ToBean toBean = new ToBean();
        org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(fromBean, toBean);
        toBeanList.add(toBean);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public List<"ToBean"> getAll()
{

**create an empty list of the Target folder**

List<'ToBean>' toBeanList = new ArrayList<'ToBean'>();

**Create a empty object of Target folder**

ToBean toBean = new ToBean();

List<'FromBean > fromBeanList = beanRepository.findAll();

//Iterate Src Bean

for(fromBean : fromBeanList)

{

BeanUtils.copyProperties(fromBean , toBean );

toBeanList .add(toBean );

}

return toBeanList ;
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you separate code and explanation into separate parts in your answer. Also format the code, refer to the [help page on Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to do it. Possibly you also want to refer to  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

What i used just now :

```
     public static List<?\> copyPropertiesArray(List<?\> source, List<?\> destination,Class<?\> destinationClass) throws CopyPropertiesException {
                
                  try {
                    //the destination size must be the same as the source size and also it must be typed correctly (thus the need for the 3rd argument)         
                     destination=Collections.nCopies(source.size(),destinationClass.newInstance()); //initialize the desination list to same size as the source         
                       for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++) {                
                          BeanUtils.copyProperties(destination.get(i), source.get(i));
                       }

                       return destination;

                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException e) {
                    
                       throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    
                    }
            }
```